# Cocos2D+Box2D iPhone : How to identify b2body and ground body collision?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I used b2ContactListener class to identify collision. All other body collision identification is successful. How can I find other b2body collision with ground body?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking exactly. If you've gotten other collision detection working, what problem are you having with ground->body?

Comment: @Emmett, Yes u r right, but problem is in other body we use sprite as userdata and we can easily identify body type with sprite tag. Now I used GroundBody->SetUserData(@"Ground Body") to identify.

Comment: oh, i see - you probably want to use fixture userdata for that. i'll add an answer

Comment: @Emmett, ground body is just edge surface..so not fixture required right?

Comment: @Emmett,  GroundBody->SetUserData(@"Ground Body") also does same thing...we need to check is that ur fixtureUserData or NSString...but your fixtureUserData requires allocation with new. So I use NSString itself. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collisions happen in box2d between fixtures, not bodies. That's why you might have some code in your contact listener that looks like

```
contact.fixtureA = contact->GetFixtureA();
contact.fixtureB = contact->GetFixtureB();
```

If you're using the sprite as the user data for each of the bodies, you still have the option of putting whatever you'd like into the fixture's userdata field. Something like this is quite helpful:

```
fixtureUserData *fUd = new fixtureUserData();
fUd->tag = INT_IDENTIFYING_GROUND_FIXTURE;
// ...
b2FixtureDef groundBoxDef;
groundBoxDef.userData = fUd;
```

Where you've defined in your .h file a struct that might look like

```
struct fixtureUserData {
    int tag;
    // ...other properties
};
```

The INT_IDENTIFYING_GROUND_FIXTURE could also be an element of an enumerated type (you might have one element of that type per collision category). If you've done this, you can then test for collision with the ground by doing

```
fixtureUserData *fBUd = (fixtureUserData *)pdContact.fixtureB->GetUserData();
if (fBUd->tag == INT_IDENTIFYING_GROUND_FIXTURE){
    // react to collision
}
```